# Is there a plateau-shaped distribution?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

I am looking for a distribution where the probability density decreases quickly after some point away from the mean, or in my own words a "plateau-shaped distribution".

Something in between the Gaussian and the uniform.

Comment: You could sum a Gaussian RV and a uniform RV.

Comment: One sometimes hears about so-called *platykurtic* distributions.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You may be looking for distribution known under the names of [generalized normal (version 1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution), [Subbotin distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/201038/does-this-distribution-have-a-name-fx-propto-exp-x-mup-beta), or exponential power distribution. It is parametrized by location $\mu$, scale $\sigma$ and shape $\beta$ with pdf

$$ \frac{\beta}{2\sigma\Gamma(1/\beta)} \exp\left[-\left(\frac{|x-\mu|}{\sigma}\right)^{\beta}\right] $$

as you can notice, for $\beta=1$ it resembles and converges to Laplace distribution, with $\beta=2$ it converges to normal, and when $\beta = \infty$ to uniform distribution.

[image]

If you are looking for software that has it implemented, you can check `normalp` library for R (Mineo and Ruggieri, 2005). What is nice about this package is that, among other things, it implements regression with generalized normally distributed errors, i.e. minimizing $L_p$ norm.

---

Mineo, A. M., & Ruggieri, M. (2005). [A software tool for the exponential power distribution: The normalp package.](https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v012i04) Journal of Statistical Software, 12(4), 1-24.

Answer (score 22):

@StrongBad's comment is a really good suggestion. The sum of a uniform RV and gaussian RV can give you exactly what you're looking for if you pick the parameters right. And it actually has a *reasonably* nice closed form solution.

The pdf of this variable is given by the expression:

$$\dfrac{1}{4a}\left[\mathrm{erf}\left(\dfrac{x+a}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)-\mathrm{erf}\left(\dfrac{x-a}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)
\right]$$

$a$ is the "radius" of the zero-mean uniform RV.
$\sigma$ is the standard deviation of the zero-mean gaussian RV.

[image: PDFs]

Comment: Reference: Bhattacharjee, G. P., Pandit, S. N. N., and Mohan, R. 1963. Dimensional chains involving rectangular and normal error-distributions. Technometrics, 5, 404–406.

Answer (score 17):

There's an infinite number of "plateau-shaped" distributions.

Were you after something more specific than "in between the Gaussian and the uniform"? That's somewhat vague.

Here's one easy one: you could always stick a half-normal at each end of a uniform:

[image: Density with uniform center and Gaussian tails]

You can control the "width" of the uniform relative to the scale of the normal so you can have wider or narrower plateaus, giving a whole class of distributions, which include the Gaussian and the uniform as limiting cases.

The density is:

$\frac{h}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu+w/2)^2} 
\mathbb{I}_{x\leq \mu-w/2}  \\
+ \:\frac{h}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma}\quad\mathbb{I}_{\mu-w/2< x\leq \mu+w/2} \\
+ \frac{h}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(x-\mu-w/2)^2} 
\mathbb{I}_{x > \mu+w/2}   $

where $h = \frac{1}{1 + w/(\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma)}$

As $\sigma \to 0$ for fixed $w$, we approach the uniform on $(\mu-w/2,\mu+w/2)$ and as $w \to 0$ for fixed $\sigma$ we approach $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

Here are some examples (with $\mu=0$ in each case):

[image: Plot of various examples of this Gaussian-tailed uniform]

We might perhaps call this density a "Gaussian-tailed uniform".

Comment: Ach! I *love* attending formal balls wearing a Gausian-tailed uniform! ;)

Comment: I appreciate the pun.

Answer (score 9):

See my "Devil's tower" distribution in here [1]:

$f(x) = 0.3334$, for $|x| < 0.9399$;
$f(x) = 0.2945/x^2$, for $0.9399 \leq |x| < 2.3242$; and
$f(x) = 0$, for $2.3242 \leq |x|$.

[image: Devil's tower density function with flat top, convex sides, cut off at extremes]

The "slip-dress"distribution is even more interesting.

It is easy to construct distributions having whatever shape you want.

[1]: Westfall, P.H. (2014)
   "Kurtosis as Peakedness, 1905 – 2014. R.I.P."
   Am. Stat. 68(3): 191–195. doi:10.1080/00031305.2014.917055
   public access pdf: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4321753/pdf/nihms-599845.pdf

Comment: Hi Peter -- I took the liberty of giving the function and inserting an image as well as giving a full reference. (If memory serves I think Kendall and Stuart giving the details of a similar debunking in their classic text. If I remember correctly - it has been a long while - I believe they also discuss that it's not heavy-tailedness)

Comment: Thanks, Glen_b. I never said kurtosis measured what the tail-index numbers measure. Rather, my article proves  kurtosis is, for a very broad class of distributions, nearly equal to E(Z^4 * I(|Z| > 1)). Thus, kurtosis clearly tells you nothing about the 'peak,' which is typically found in the range {Z: |Z| <1}. Rather, it is determined mostly by the tails. Call it E(Z^4 * I(|Z| > 1)) if the term "heavy-tailedness" has another meaning.

Comment: Also, @Glen_b which tail-index are you referring to? There are infinitely many. Tail crossings don't define "tailedness" properly. According to some tail crossing definitions of tail heaviness, N(0,1) is more "heavy-tailed" than .9999*U(-1,1) + .0001*U(-1000,1000), although the latter is obviously more heavy tailed, despite having finite tails. And, BTW, the latter has extremely high kurtosis, unlike N(0,1).

Comment: I can't find me saying "tail index" anywhere in my comment; I am not quite sure what you're referring to there when you say "which tail-index are you referring to". If you mean the bit about heavy-tailedness the best thing to do is check what Kendall and Stuart actually say; I believe there they actually compare the asymptotic ratio of densities for symmetric standardized variables, but it might have been survivor functions perhaps; the point was theirs, not mine

Comment: Strange. Well, in any event, Kendall and Stuart got it wrong. Kurtosis is obviously a measure of tail weight as my theorems prove.

Comment: Considering they're discussing explicit counterexamples; one possibility is that what your theorems actually establish kurtosis to be is not as unequivocally all reasonable measures of tail weight as you're suggesting just there. If they were to use any reasonably well-accepted measure and from it show a counterexample, the apparent generality of your claim just there would seem to have a problem, not the counterexample.

Comment: Well, the "tail-crossing" ("accepted") definition is obviously flawed because it states that N(0,1) is heavier-tailed than .9999U(-1,1) +.0001U(-1000,1000). I really don't know if there are any "well accepted" measures of tailedness. It just depends on the application. For example, the variance of the variance estimate depends on tail weight through kurtosis only, so that's the tailweight definition that makes sense there. Also, what about "well-accepted" definitions of "peakedness"? A stream of math literature states that normals with smaller variance are more "peaked."  Is this "accepted"?

Answer (score 5):

Lots of nice answers. The solution proffered here has 2 features: (i) that it has a particularly simple functional form, and (ii) that the resulting distribution necessarily produces a plateau-shaped pdf (not just as a special case). I'm not sure if this already has a name in the literature, but absent same, let us call it a Plateau distribution with pdf $f(x)$:

$$f(x) = k \frac{1}{1 + x^{2 a}}  \quad \quad \text{for } x \in \mathbb{R}$$

where:

- parameter $a$ is a positive integer, and
- $k$ is a constant of integration:  $k = \frac{a}{\pi} \sin \left(\frac{\pi}{2 a}\right)$

Here is a plot of the pdf, for different values of parameter $a$:

[image]

.

As parameter $a$ becomes large, the density tends towards a Uniform(-1,1) distribution. The following plot also compares to a standard Normal (gray dashed):

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another one (**EDIT**: I simplified it now. **EDIT2**: I simplified it even further, though now the picture doesn't really reflect this exact equation):

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{3 \cdot \alpha} \cdot
\log{\left(
  \frac{\cosh{\left(\alpha \cdot a\right)}+
    \cosh{\left(\alpha \cdot x\right)}}
    {\cosh{\left(\alpha \cdot b\right)}+
    \cosh{\left(\alpha \cdot x\right)}}
  \right)}
$$

Clunky, I know, but here I took advantage of the fact that $\log(\cosh(x))$ approaches a line as $x$ increases.

Basically you have control over how smooth is the transition ($alpha$). If $a = 2$ and $b = 1$ I guarantee it's a valid probability density (sums to 1). If you choose other values then you'll have to renormalize it.

---

Here is some sample code in R:

```
f = function(x, a, b, alpha){
  y = log((cosh(2*alpha*pi*a)+cosh(2*alpha*pi*x))/(cosh(2*alpha*pi*b)+cosh(2*alpha*pi*x)))
  y = y/pi/alpha/6
  return(y)
}
```

`f` is our distribution. Let's plot it for a sequence of `x`

```
plot(0, type = "n", xlim = c(-5,5), ylim = c(0,0.4))
x = seq(-100,100,length.out = 10001L)

for(i in 1:10){
  y = f(x = x, a = 2, b = 1, alpha = seq(0.1,2, length.out = 10L)[i]); print(paste("integral =", round(sum(0.02*y), 3L)))
  lines(x, y, type = "l", col = rainbow(10, alpha = 0.5)[i], lwd = 4)
}
legend("topright", paste("alpha =", round(seq(0.1,2, length.out = 10L), 3L)), col = rainbow(10), lwd = 4)
```

Console output:

```
#[1] "integral = 1"
#[1] "integral = 1"
#[1] "integral = 1"
#[1] "integral = 1"
#[1] "integral = 1"
#[1] "integral = 1"
#[1] "integral = 1"
#[1] "integral = NaN" #I suspect underflow, inspecting the plots don't show divergence at all
#[1] "integral = NaN"
#[1] "integral = NaN"
```

And plot:

[image: My distribution based on log cosh]

You could change `a` and `b`, approximately the start and end of the slope respectively, but then further normalization would be needed, and I didn't calculate it (that's why I'm using `a = 2` and `b = 1` in the plot).

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for something very simple, with a central plateau and the sides of a triangle distribution, you can for instance combine N triangle distributions, N depending on the desired ratio between the plateau and the descent. Why triangles, because their sampling functions already exist in most languages. You randomly sort from one of them.

In R that would give:

```
library(triangle)
rplateau = function(n=1){
  replicate(n, switch(sample(1:3, 1), rtriangle(1, 0, 2), rtriangle(1, 1, 3), rtriangle(1, 2, 4)))
}
hist(rplateau(1E5), breaks=200)
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty one: the product of two logistic functions.

```
(1/B) * 1/(1+exp(A*(x-B))) * 1/(1+exp(-A*(x+B)))
```

This has the benefit of not being piecewise.

B adjusts the width and A adjusts the steepness of the drop off. Shown below are B=1:6 with A=2. Note: I haven't taken the time to figure out how to properly normalize this.

[image: Plateau distribution]