# Multivariate Regression with Uniform Errors

Tags: regression, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-regression

I'd like to know if there is a multivariate regression model with uniform errors. More specifically, I'd like to find the Maximum Likelihood Estimators for $\beta^a$ and $\beta^b$. The model is given by

\begin{equation}
 \left( \begin{array}{c}
 Y^a \\
 Y^b
 \end{array} \right) = 
 %
 \left( \begin{array}{c}
 \mu_i^a \\
 \mu_i^b
 \end{array} \right) + 
 \Sigma^{1/2}
 %
 \left( \begin{array}{c}
 \varepsilon_i^a \\
 \varepsilon_i^b
 \end{array} \right) \qquad i = 1, \ldots, n
\end{equation},

$Y^a$ and $Y^b$ are random variables jointly uniformly distributed and response variable, $\left( \begin{array}{c}
 \varepsilon_i^a \\
 \varepsilon_i^b
 \end{array} \right)$ is uniformly distributed, $\mu_i^a = (X^a)^T\beta^a$, and $\mu_i^b = (X^b)^T\beta^b$. $X^a = (X_1^a, \ldots, X_p^a)$ and $X^b = (X_1^b, \ldots, X_p^b)$ are $p$ non-stochastic variables, called regressors.

Comment: You can use regression with Subbotin errors: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/203629/is-there-a-plateau-shaped-distribution/203634#203634

Comment: @Tim That's a good answer--the post you reference is not a mere duplicate.

Comment: @whuber I didn't suggest it is, I thought it may be helpful for OP

Comment: @Tim That's a good answer and start point, but I'd like to solve the problem for bi-dimensional uniform errors.